# Keras encoder - decoder for MNIST ->new images

Tags: keras, mnist, encoder, decoder

I am trying to fit a encoder-decoder-network in Keras which predicts images from the MNIST data set in a very good way. Now, I have changed the image input so that apples are shown. As a reference here is a link:
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2133/2203251029_008e350792.jpg

I am converting converted the image to grayscale and resizing them to 28x28. However, when I now run the same network as for the MNIST data set then I am getting only a black image as a prediction. Do you have any ideas how I could improve my network?
Here is my code of the network:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (2,2),padding='valid')(input_img)
x =BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides = (2,2),padding='valid')(x)

x =BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (2, 2), strides = (2,2),  padding='valid')(x)
x =BatchNormalization()(x)
encoded = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (1, 1), padding='valid')(encoded)
x =BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((3, 3))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding='valid')(x)
x =BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3))(x)
x =BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (2, 2), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

How can I improve my network? Any hints are much appreciated!

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: Encoder and decoder are independent from each other, so, there is absolutely no way for the decoder to know what the original image was. If you hadn't trained any apples before, it will not understand apples. You must make it train apples along with numbers first. Add the apple image to the training data and to the desired output, and do some training. --- But for complex patterns, it may be necessary to have bigger and bigger nets.

Comment: Is it your intention to print out really bigger images?

Comment: I am trying to build a CycleGAN in Keras, but once I am training the images and predict them at the end of the network, then the prediction is that my generated image is white ..

Comment: You can download the dataset already encoded as tiff images here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/